# avoiding passing offset to C# MemoryStream write

Tags: c#

I have a MemoryStream object that is getting passed around from function to function, and each function adds something to it (could be byte could be more).
There are matching functions in read.

Can I avoid updating the offset by myself and let "the stream" handle it?
(such as `stream.Write(byte[]);` similar to `stream.WriteByte(byte);`)

I'm a bit confused from all the documentation in the area

Comment: Those offsets are into your byte array, and not into the stream. So I don't know why you're updating the offset. If you want to write a full array, just set the offset to 0, and the length to the length of the array.

Comment: @CodesInChaos +1, Maybe you could write this as an answer, I strongly suspects it is actually the source of the OP's issue (confusion between offsets of buffer and stream)

Comment: Oh... indeed I thought that the offset is for the stream itself... thanks guys...

Comment: should I delete the question? or do you think it has a value staying here - (clearly the correct answer is - you misinterpreted the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) that always sets the offset to 0(i.e. writes from the zero index in the buffer).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Write(this MemoryStream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid passing the offset around.

When you write to a memory stream, its [`Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.position.aspx) property is incremented by the size of the item(s) written, so the next one written will be after the previous one.

You can therefore just pass around the memory stream.